# what exactly it means in python that: False==(False or True) is False?

Tags: python, boolean, logic

## Operator precedence in boolean-logic in python

```
print(False==True or False) #answer is True
print(False==(False or True))# is it True or False if either why?
print((False==False)or True) # answer is True`
```

Comment: `(False or True)` equals *True*, so when you then do `False == *that expression*`, you get *False*.

Comment: You should read the following Wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Answer (score 1):

It is `False`.

```
print(False==(False or True))
```

You need to evaluate the boolean value in paranthesis first. In paranthesis `(False or True)` evaluates `True` because  of `or` then `False==True` evaluates `False` obviously .

Answer (score 1):

```
print(False==True or False) #answer is **False**
print(False==(False or True))# Answer is **False**
print((False==False)or True) # answer is **True`**
```

For print(False==(False or True))

```
step1:  print(False==(False or True))
step 2: step 1 become print(False==True) **because (0+1=1)**
step 3: print(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate the expression step-by-step:

```
False == (False or True)
```

=

```
False == True
```

=

```
False
```

Answer (score 0):

The `or` operator has a lower precedence than the equality operator `==`. And `()` has the highest precedence among the three.

So in the case:

1. `print(False==True or False)`, the right side of the expression `True or False` is evaluated last as `==` has a higher precedence than `or`. The first expression `False==True` is evaluated to `False`.

   Now the expression becomes `False or False` so it results in `False`.
2. `print(False==(False or True))` the second part of the expression `(False or True)`results in `True` as `()` has the highest precedence and `False==True` is `False`.
3. `print((False==False)or True)` the expression `(False==False)` is `True` due to the `()` precedence then the `or` is applied to the resulting expression, `True or True` it is `True`.

Comment: ok, the logic is (True or False )  =True      or (False or True)=True in python. Thanks a lot

Comment: @D Gurung Yes, if there is any `True` in an expression having `or` it becomes `True`.